# Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin. Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle

**Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.**

После обновления проекта до Gradle 4.1 и студии с 2.3.3 до 3.0.0 начала выходить такая ошибка.

Не понимаю, как определить, какая из библиотек требует `annotationProcessor` вместо `apt`.

Каждую если библиотеку проверять, это же не дело. И не на каждой странице библиотеки написано об `annotationProcessor`.

Есть ли какой-то вариант проверки, какая из библиотек выдаёт ошибку?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'blade'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.test.app1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(path: ':vksdk_library', configuration: 'default')
    implementation('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.14') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
    }
    implementation('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-core-parent:1.4.14') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
    }
    implementation('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-cache:1.4.14') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
    }
    //Retrofit
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    //OkHttp
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.5.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    /*io.apptik.widget:multislider:1.3 появилась, но она не подходит внешне*/

    //    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0'
    implementation 'eu.davidea:flipview:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.shadow-layout:library:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.github.frankiesardo:icepick:2.3.6'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.frankiesardo:icepick-processor:2.3.6' // annotation Processor

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.githang:viewpagerindicator:2.4.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.linwoain.library:library:1.0'
    implementation('io.apptik.widget:multislider:1.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support:appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support:design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support:support'
    }
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    implementation 'ru.ok:odnoklassniki-android-sdk:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:3.0.1.2.original@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.2@aar'
    implementation('com.mikepenz:crossfader:1.5.0@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support:appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support:support'
    }
    implementation 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu:2.0.0'
    implementation('com.tolstykh.textviewrichdrawable:textview-rich-drawable:0.3.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support:support-v4'
    }
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.6'
    implementation('io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.3'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.3'
    implementation files('libs/zxing_core.jar')
    implementation('me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

И project.level:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        classpath 'eu.f3rog.blade:plugin:2.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: оффтоп: Зачем вам glide, picasso и UIL в одном проекте?

Comment: @katso, знаю, можно и одной либой. Они использовались раньше, когда у каждой были свои существенные преимущества перед другими либами, поэтому использовались каждая для своей задачи. Сейчас 
 они привязаны сильно, в будущем сделаю одной

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в библиотеке `blade` (classpath 'eu.f3rog.blade:plugin:2.2.0')